# Apply Javascript to certain html list ul's only

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

so I have the code below and I dont want it to be applied to all ul's, just the ones in a certain div. How can I do that? (The line I am talking about is the one where it says: `carousel = $("ul");`)

```
var carousel;
$(document).ready(function () {
    carousel = $("ul");
    carousel.itemslide(
    {

    start: 1,
    swipe_out: true,
    }


    );
});
```

Comment: You need to target your ul with the div's class like `$(".my-div ul")`

Comment: Or give the appropriate `<ul>` a common class and use that as selector. `$('ul.my-carousel-class')`

Comment: add specific class to 'ul' you want to target and use that

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`<ul class="classname">`
it will give all the ul a common class. and then can use

```
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.classname li');
```

something like this, it will select all the < li > from that < ul >